# Drupal: getting exact date from created column in ddbb

Tags: sql, drupal

So I'm trying to extract the **created**, access and **login** dates from the users in the database of a Drupal site. But the values are like: 1377783381, 1384248801...

I have tried to do this in the SQL:

```
SELECT  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL us.created SECOND), us.name
FROM users us
```

But it returns dates from 1970 - 1974 and dates should go from 2013 - 2018 approx.

The truth is that I don't know what represents that numbers, but they aren't seconds.

Comment: How about using views module for this? There should be some formatting option for date and the module will know in what format those dates are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the values are milliseconds.  Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL us.created/1000 SECOND), us.name
FROM users us;
```

For some reason, MySQL supports `second`s and `microseconds`, but not `milliseconds`.

Actually, as I think about it, subtracting a millisecond value from the current time doesn't make sense.  More likely, this is a unix time value:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(us.created), us.name
FROM users us;
```

Comment: Yes, they are Unix time value. I have tested the second query and it returns the correct dates.